# Get time from date and time using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I extract `12:05 AM` from `7/16/2016 12:05:00 AM` using Regex?

I've made it this far

```
test = "7/16/2016 12:05:00 AM"
test.match(/^(\S+) (.*)/)[2]
> "12:05:00 AM"
```

but I can't figure out how to remove the seconds. Plus, if there's a simpler/more efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do, please let me know.

I would rather not rely on third-party libraries like moment.js

---

NOTE: My desired output is `12:05 AM` and not just `12:05`

Comment: search for the first colon (:) and retrive the 2 chars before and after it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look explicitly for the digits and colon, lopping off the last two before matching your am/pm. We also make the second hour digit optional, in case we are just matching against "3:14:16 pm":

```
var test = "7/16/16 12:05:00 AM";
var matches = test.match(/(\d\d?:\d\d):\d\d(\s[ap]m)/i);
var time = matches && (matches[1] + matches[2]);
// time === "12:05 AM"
```

---

Just to note for fullness of regex, you could also use curly braces to determine the number of digits to count *(I didn't above, because it's more characters in the end when it's just 1-2)*. Both the following and above will match the same string:

```
var matches = test.match(/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}):\d{2}(\s[ap]m)/i;
```

Comment: You may want `(\d{1,2}:\d{2})` as your first group ... the fact that the time carries the am/pm suffix suggests there may not be a leading `0` as "03:14:16 AM", it would likely be "3:14:16 AM"

Comment: Thanks! I've cleaned it up according to @StephenP's suggestion: `test.match(/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}):\d{2}(\s[ap]m)/i);`

Comment: @Katie, haha, I just did the same to the answer. Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

A simple and short alternative is to match the parts you *don't* want, and replace them by empty strings.

```
test.replace(/^\S*\s*|:\d\d(?!:)/g, "")
```

Explanation:

- `^\S*\s*` - matches the date and the first space
- `:\d\d(?!:)` - matches the seconds and the colon preceding it; the negative lookahead prevents the pattern from matching the minutes
- `g` - 'global' flag; need this because we have two matches to be replaced

Try it here:

```js
window.go = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var output = input.replace(/^\S*\s*|:\d\d(?!:)/g, "");
    document.getElementById("output").value = output;
};
```

```html
<input id="input" value="7/16/2016 12:05:00 AM">
<button onclick="go()">Click me!</button>
<input id="output">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easier way:

```
var time = test.split(' ')[1]
time = time.substring(0, time.length - 3)+' '+test.split(' ')[2]
```

Also, if you need to work with dates and time I would suggest [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

```
moment(test).format('h:mm A')
```

Comment: You forgot to put the AM back on the end :)