# Check if time exists in date string typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this string returned to me `2022/2/23`. And some other times `2022/2/23 16:32:23`.
I want to make this: if dateString has no time in it then blabla.

How can I check if my string has a time string in it?

Comment: I'd consider using a JS regex.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403498/421195

Comment: Not related to TypeScript in any way. This could be a JavaScript question but as it is formulated it is generic and does not depend on a language at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using includes to check if there is a `:` present:

```
const checkIfIncludesTime = (dateStr: string): boolean => dateStr.includes(':');
```

You can also use regex for this one:

```
const checkIfIncludesTime = (dateStr: string): boolean => /:/.test(dateStr);
```

Hope this helps